# Very basic encryption program

Tags: c, encryption, file-io, xor

I am creating a very basic encryption program using XOR to encrypt a user file and decrypt it again. What's happening however is when I encrypt I get a long line of the same 6 letters and when I try to decrypt it doesn't work. Can anyone spot the problem? Also, I will want to replace the XOR with a basic encryption method of my own but retain the same code except for the key. Will this be possible? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
FILE *fp1, *fp2;
char* key;
int c;

key = argv[1];

    if(*key != '\0')
    {
    fp1 = fopen(argv[2],"rb");
        if(fp1 != NULL)
        {
            fp2 = fopen(argv[3],"wb");
            if (fp2 != NULL)
            {
            while((c=getc(fp1)!=EOF))
            {
                if(!*key)key = argv[1];
                c ^=*(key++);

                putc(c, fp2);
            }
            fclose(fp2);
            }
        fclose(fp1);
        }
    }
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Your indentation could be improved; eg: the first fopen/fclose are at different indentations, the 2nd pair at the same indentation ...

Comment: Just a side note: It may be a good idea to check `argc` & make sure you have enough arguments to work on

Comment: `return 0;` is usually used to indicate success to the Operating System; `return 1;` likely indicates failure. You may want to review your return value.

Comment: Will fix indentation that was just for my own working I should have amended it before posting sorry! Return 1 will be set to 0. Don't understand what you mean about argc however. Is my code incorrect?

Comment: If you don't supply the correct number (and type) of arguments your program will "explode". Try `yourprogram topsecretkey input.txt` without saying where to write the coded data.

Comment: Yes I see, the program ran but obviously nothing happened. Fair point will review that also. Thanks very much for the help everyone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check your parenthesis: the while should be

```
while((c=getc(fp1))!=EOF)
```

Comment: Bang on that was the problem thank you! What about the other question I had? Would it be possible for me to write my own encryption algorithm and replace XOR in this code?

Comment: Yes, replace your line `c ^= *(key++);` with your algorithm, eg: `c = youralgo(c, *key++);`

Comment: Thank you so much pmg very much appreciated, and indeed everyone else. Great help to be had from this site!